# Comparing two csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have this program that takes two csv files into consideration. It looks at "testclaims" (one column many rows) and sees if any words in "masterlist"(one column, many rows) are within the rows of "testclaims." If the rows in "testclaims" contains any word in "masterlist" it will list it into a new .csv file called "output." This part of the program works great.

The part that I can't seem to figure out is to output all the remaining rows in "testclaims" that don't contain ANY words in "masterlist" into another csv called "output2" I would think that the last two lines of my code should get this to work, but it's not outputting what I want. I hope I've explained this clearly enough. Here's my code:

```
    import csv

    with open("testclaims.csv") as file1, open("masterlist.csv") as file2,
        open("stopwords.csv") as file3,\
        open("output.csv", "wb+") as file4, open("output2.csv", "wb+") as file5:
        writer = csv.writer(file4)
        writer2 = csv.writer(file5)
        key_words = [word.strip() for word in file2.readlines()]
        stop_words = [word.strip() for word in file3.readlines()]
        internal_stop_words = [' a ', ' an ', ' and ', 'as ', ' at ', ' be ', 'ed ',
              'ers ', ' for ',\
              ' he ', ' if ', ' in ', ' is ', ' it ', ' of ', ' on ', ' to ', 'her ', 'hers '\
              ' do ', ' did ', ' a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' d ', ' e ', ' f ', ' g ', ' h ', ' i ',\
              ' j ', ' k ', ' l ', ' m ', 'n ', ' n', ' nc ' ' o ', ' p ', ' q ', ' r ', ' s ',\
              ' t ', ' u ', ' v ', ' w ', ' x ', ' y ', 'z ', ',', '"', 'ers ', ' th ', ' gc ',\
                       ' so ', ' ot ', ' ft ', ' ow ', ' ir ', ' ho ', ' er ', ]
        for row in file1:
            row = row.strip()
            row = row.lower()
            for stop in stop_words:
                if stop in row:
                    row = row.replace(stop," ")
            for stopword in internal_stop_words:
                if stopword in row:
                    row = row.replace(stopword," ")
            for key in key_words:
                if key in row:
                    writer.writerow([key, row])
                elif key not in row:
                    writer2.writerow([row])
```

What output2 is outputting is every row in "testclaims" repeated multiple times.

For example if "testclaims" contains this one column:

```
    Happy
    Sad
    Angry
    Dog
    Cat
```

"output2" is outputting a csv that prints this one column:

```
    Happy
    Happy
    Happy
    Happy
    Happy
    Sad
    Sad
    Sad
    Sad
    Angry
    Angry
    Angry
    Angry
    Angry
    Dog
    Dog
    Dog
    Dog
    Dog
    Cat
    Cat
    Cat
    Cat
    Cat
```

And it doesn't output the same number of each row either.

Comment: how does your csv files look like and how your intended output? A minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: @yoopoo it repeatedly prints each row in "testclaims" multiple times. For example there are 1000 rows in "testclaims" but output2 outputs 33140 rows

Comment: make a minimal example!

Comment: @yoopoo Please take a look at the edits for an example. That's just a minimal example. It actually outputs them amount 30 or so times. Different amount for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a double for loop and each time you print the row, but you only want it at most once per row.
you should adjust your last two lines:

```
for row in file1:

    ...

    for key in key_words:
        if key in row:
            writer.writerow([key, row])
    if not any(key in row for key in key_words):
        writer2.writerow([row])
```

Comment: Where do you see the "for key in file 1:" Do I add that in somewhere?

Comment: i meant row sry. Only the last two lines differ.